# How to draw a string at a specific position on a pdf page in java using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf coordinate (x, y) as input . I need to draw a string at the given input coordinate[Eg :- (x,y)=(200,250)]. I am using pdfbox , When I am using the below method moveTextPositionByAmount I am not getting the exact position.Even i have tried with moveTo(). Please help me how to draw the string at an exact position ?

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,true,true);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(xindex, yindex);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(color);
contentStream.drawString(comment);                      
contentStream.stroke();
contentStream.endText();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to be at the given position? PDF interprets that position as the **baseline** of the text.

Comment: I want to draw a string at that position , when i tried by executing the above code , it draws the text with large variation when compared with the original one.

Comment: I spotted one possible issue, cf. my answer below. If using the proposed fix you still have issues, please supply a sample document changed by your code illustrating the issue and explain where you got those target coordinates from anyway because there are multiple coordinate systems at work inside PDFs, and some PDF processors bring along their own.

Comment: Sample Data X:-121,Y:-305,W:-262,h:-104. Please check the below link for screenshot. [link]http://tinypic.com/r/11b6lap/8. I am also working on drawing rectangle . I was successful in getting the exact output when the same coordinates are used . I have used contentStream.fillRect(xValue,yValue,wValue,hValue) for drawing a rectangle ,but the problem arises when using drawstring.

Comment: A screen shot does only help if the PDF is also supplied. Furthermore you have not explained where you get those coordinates from. They might have to be transformed because there are multiple coordinate systems which might be involved here.

Comment: I will get the coordinates from external application . Once the coordinates are transformed , they works fine while I am using fillRect()/addRect() method. But it does not work for drawString()

Comment: Please supply a sample PDF illustrating the issue. Probably with both a rectangle (which is ok, as you say) and a string. And explain where you expected the string to be.

Comment: Sorry , I am unable to share the document . My network is not allowing me to upload a document.

Comment: Then it is hard to tell. Just some ideas for you to check: Are there any changes to the current transformation matrix? Do you correctly consider that the glyph origin is on the baseline, not the ascent or descent line? Do you consider the media box?

Comment: I did not considered any transformation matrix , just the code is as it is as shown above.Just I will get the coordinates like X:-121,Y:-305,W:-262,h:-104 and the page size is width = 612 & height =792 and have to draw the string .

Comment: Which is the origin of your coordinates, are the positive y coordinates above or below, is *X,Y* the lower left of the rectangle, what is the meaning of a negative width or height (you mention *W:-262,h:-104*), where inside that box do you want to draw the string?

Answer (score 11):

### Getting rid of graphic state changes from the existing page content

You use the `PDPageContentStream` constructor with two `boolean` arguments:

```
new PDPageContentStream(document, page,true,true);
```

This constructor is implemented as:

```
this(document, sourcePage, appendContent, compress, false);
```

i.e. it calls the constructor with three `boolean` arguments using `false` for the final one. This final `boolean` argument is documented as:

```
* @param resetContext Tell if the graphic context should be reseted.
```

Thus, you append to the page content without resetting the graphic context. This means that any changes to the current transformation matrix done in the existing page content still transforms your coordinates. To prevent that from happening you should use the `PDPageContentStream` constructor with three `boolean` arguments:

```
new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true);
```

Using this one can easily position text.

### Drawing rectangles and test

The OP mentioned that he was successful drawing rectangles but not drawing text.

The following code

```
PDPage firstPage = allPages.get(0);
PDRectangle pageSize = firstPage.findMediaBox();

float x = 121;
float y = 305;
float w = 262;
float h = 104;

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, firstPage, true, true, true);

contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.yellow);
contentStream.fillRect(pageSize.getLowerLeftX() + x, pageSize.getLowerLeftY() + y, w, h);

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(pageSize.getLowerLeftX() + x, pageSize.getLowerLeftY() + y);
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.red);
contentStream.drawString("My Text Here");
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
```

results in

[image: Screenshot of result]

as would be expected.

### Meaning of input coordinates must be explained

The OP also mentioned *X:-121,Y:-305,W:-262,h:-104* as *coordinates from external application* in his comments.

As PDFs most often have positive coordinates inside the media box, these X and Y coordinates make no sense for PDFs in general.

Furthermore the OP was *unable to share the document*.

Therefore, it could not be found out whether or not those negative coordinates make sense for his special PDF.

Additionally negative values for widths and height are accepted by the rectangle drawing operations, but if used for text, they might imply that the Y coordinate does not denote the baseline, or that the text is not expected to start at X but to end there, or that the text shall be mirrored, or, or, or...

Thus, the meaning of those negative coordinates and dimensions must first be explained. *Which is the origin of those coordinates, are the positive y coordinates above or below, is X,Y the lower left of the rectangle, what is the meaning of a negative width or height, where in relation to X, Y shall the string be drawn?*

Comment: I could not find the above constructor in the api .[link] https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.html

Comment: Well, that is a bad sign concerning the state of that API documentation because the constructor has been introduced in December 2010. It has been present in the releases at least since PDFBox 1.4.0.

Comment: I mean the coordinates are X=121,Y=305,W=262,h=104 . This one worked for me .Thanks .But I got the output with another solution.

Comment: What units the x, y, width, and height given in?  When I try out the example you give that draws a yellow rectangle, I open up my PDF viewer at zoom level 100%, and measure the width of the rectangle in pixels.  It's 350 px wide, not 262 like in the code.

Comment: The default user space unit in PDFs is the [DTP point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)#Desktop_publishing_point), 1/72 inch.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this one worked for me .

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,true,true);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(xindex, yindex);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(color);
contentStream.drawString(comment);                      
contentStream.endText();
```

Comment: You seem to use an old PDFBox version; in early 2013 checks had been added which would make your `contentStream.moveTo(0,0)` throw an exception. The reason: `moveTo` and `stroke` add path creation or path drawing operations. Such operations are forbidden inside a text object (`beginText` ... `endText`) and, therefore, create a broken PDF. Most PDF viewers ignore this error, though.

Comment: Yes . I am using older version of PDFBox as the project which I am working has been developed earlier and I have to use those jar files only . Sorry , stroke() is not used in my code .

Comment: *stroke() is not used in my code* - strictly speaking `moveTo` is not allowed inside text objects, either...

Comment: Don`t know exactly but it worked .

contentStream.moveTo(0,0);     contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(xValue,yValue);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(color);
contentStream.drawString(comment);
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();

Comment: Your `contentStream.moveTo(0,0)` starts creating a path. Path creation must end with a path drawing operation. Instead of such an operation, you begin a text object. Thus, strictly speaking your solution creates invalid PDFs.