# PDFBox: Inconsistent co-ordinate system, how do I draw a rectangle?

Tags: java, pdfbox, coordinate-systems

This is the piece of code I have written to highlight texts in a PDF. This method takes PDDocument object, Page Number, Rectangle points(x,y,w,h), color and transparency.

```
 public PDDocument highlightText(PDDocument document, Integer pageNo,Float[] rectPoints, Color color, Float transparency) throws Exception{
        /* highlighttext() takes document, page no and rectangle points[x,y,width,height] */
        try
        {
            PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNo);
            PDExtendedGraphicsState extendedGraphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
            // Set the transparency/opacity
            extendedGraphicsState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(transparency);

            try(PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,AppendMode.APPEND,true)){

                //use graphic state
                contents.setGraphicsStateParameters(extendedGraphicsState);
                contents.setNonStrokingColor(color);
                //Rectangle points(x,y,w,h) - takes top left corner as (0,0) origin
                contents.addRect(rectPoints[0], rectPoints[1], rectPoints[2], rectPoints[3]);
                contents.fill();
            }


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }

        return document;
    }
```

**Question:**
Issue here is with the Rectangle points (especially with Y co-ordinate)
For a PDF I created using Microsoft Word Document (Using export), To draw a box, I gave the points [0,500,100,100], then rectangle was drawn considering that Origin was at **BOTTOM-LEFT** corner. Okay, that's great, right!

For a PDF I created using Google Chrome (Using ctrl+p, save as file), To draw a box, I gave the points [0,500,100,100], now the rectangle was drawn at exactly opposite Y axis (considering that Origin is at **TOP-LEFT** corner). I am totally confused now, how addRect() takes the points. How do I fix this so that, if I give any kind of PDF, it takes any one location as Origin either bottom left or top left ?

Comment: Please try adding a fifth parameter `true` to `new PDPageContentStream`. If it doesn't work, please link to the PDF.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That worked. Could you please explain briefly about the fifth argument?

Comment: Glad it woks for you. There is a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24992794/535646 . Consider upvoting that one, then delete your question as it is a duplicate IMHO.

Comment: I can't upvote, my reputation is quite low. But thanks for your answer again, will delete this question.

Comment: it is still there.