# Not able to add icon on desired coordinates on PDF using ApachePdfBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am using ApachePdfBox for PDF processing. I am trying to draw an icon onto the of the PDF image but it always ends up by putting the icon on bottom left of the PDF image. I am not able to figure it out how to calculate the right coordinates and resolution of PDF. It is working perfectly with one file while failing for the attached one.

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfInputStream)) {
       PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
       try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false)) {
           PDImageXObject imageXObject = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(imageFile);
           int pdfWidth = (int) page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
           int pdfHeight = (int) page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
         contentStream.drawImage(imageXObject, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
       }
  }
 Path tempFile = tempDirectory.newTempFile(".pdf");
 document.save(tempFile.toFile());
```

You can find the PDF [over here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BynSOX5ZwJhAODZwNWZ3dDhJSUhHTC1OYnZkcnhhRnlBVGhr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try adding a fifth parameter (true) to the PDPageContentStream constructor. (Your question is a duplicate, but I'm too busy now :-))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDFBox : PDPageContentStream's append mode misbehaving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27919730/1729265) or [How to draw a string at a specific position on a pdf page in java using pdfbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992794/1729265)

Comment: Furthermore, you ignore that the lower left needs not be the original of the coordinate system. It is so here and it is so often, but for a general solution you also need to take the lower left coordinates of the crop box into account.